# differential equation and infectious diseases dynamics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would appreciate if I could get some feedback from my solution to the question below:

Question: A swine flu epidemic starts in an isolated population of 1,000 pigs. Let I(t) and N(t) be the number of infected and non-infected pigs at time t such that N(t) = 1000 – I(t). The rate at which I(t) is increasing is proportional to I(t)N(t). When 100 pigs are infected, the rate at which new infections are occurring is 90 pigs per day.

(a) If 20 pigs are infected at time t = 0, when will 90% of the population be infected?

My answer to the above question was 4 days.

I got this after solving the equation: $I = I_{0}e^{Nkt}$.

I then solved for the equation: $900 = 20e^{0.001*980*t}$ which gives t = 4 days.

Any other thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: I got a final answer different than 4 days.

Comment: @paw88789, did you get 38days by any chance?

Comment: I got $\ln(441)\approx 6.1$ days

Comment: @paw88789, absolutely right! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{dI(t)}{dt} = kI(t)(1000-I(t))$ where $k$ is the proportionality constant mentioned in your question. We are given that $\frac{dI(t)}{dt} = 90$ when $I(t) = 100$, which gives $k = \frac{1}{1000}$.

You can compute the expression for $I(t)$ by computing the integrals below. You will need partial fraction expansion for the left hand side. You should then get an expression for $I(t)$ in terms of $I(0)$ and $t$, which will answer your question.
$$\int\frac{dI}{kI(1000-I)} = \int dt$$

Comment: I already solved this and I got something along the lines of $I = I_{0}e^{Nkt}$.

Comment: This is what I got: $\ln(\frac{I(t)(1000-I(0))}{(1000-I(t))I(0)}) = t$. Substituting the values in the question I get $t = \ln 441$, which is a bit above 6.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I'll solve it again myself.

Comment: Google "logistic equation".

Comment: @HansLundmark, Thanks, got it.